# Incoming... For info, decipher this

Tags: cipher

The message that might bring happiness to those who remember:

.---- .---- ----- .---- ----- ----- .---- ----- / .---- ----- .---- .---- .---- .---- ----- ----- / .---- ----- ----- .---- ----- ----- .---- .---- / .---- ----- ----- .---- .---- .---- .---- ----- / .---- ----- ----- ----- .---- .---- ----- .---- / .---- ----- ----- .---- ----- .---- ----- -----

Answer (score 5):

The hidden text is

> `-Clark`
>
>  Replacing `.----` with 1 and `-----` with 0 (morse code) and negating every digit, we obtain six binary numbers: 00101101, 01000011, 01101100, 01100001, 01110010 and 01101011 which are the ASCII codes for `-Clark`